# Regarding the reaction of xenon with fluorine gas

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, stoichiometry

In my textbook, under the topic about xenon-fluorine compounds, the following three equations are mentioned:

> $\ce{Xe(g) + F_2(g) -> XeF2(s)}$ (Xenon in excess / 2:1 ratio)
>
> $\ce{Xe(g) + 2F_2(g) -> XeF4(s)}$ (1:5 ratio)
>
> $\ce{Xe(g) + 3F_2(g) -> XeF6(s)}$ (1:20 ratio)

I am having trouble understanding how these ratios are obtained. For example, if we consider the second equation, 1:5 is definitely not the molar ratio, and it doesn't seem to be the mass ratio either. Similarly, for the other two equations too, I am not able to find a way to get the corresponding ratios.

Could anyone please explain on what basis are these ratios obtained?

Comment: They are assumed to be experimentally determined molar ratios to get the best (or good at least) yield of the particular fluoride.